# How to personalize info on a page?

Tags: php, html, ajax, web

Using PHP.

So I have a login system in place and a database set up with information about the users. Now let's say I want to link the user to a page after login and that page will contain his info. What is the most common way of doing this? Do I echo the whole HTML from a PHP file, or should I make an HTML page and alter it with AJAX somehow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imho the authentication page checks the credential with DB (can be in classical form, or AJAX form), if credentials are OK, it redirects to the homepage, the account page or whatever you want, but for me it always redirects.

Comment: There are several frameworks by which you can make Dynamic web sites and If you want to create it with core than use global variable or database fetch data with php variables and show using html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is used within html. You can create the .php file and have raw html in there. Ex:

```
  <?php
      session_start(); //Start user session to access $_SESSION variable
      echo 'Hello '.$_SESSION['username'].'.'; //If you had a username variable
  ?>
  <div class="html-class">
     This is raw html.
  </div>
  <div>
   <?php echo 'This is content rendered by PHP'; ?>
  </div>
```

As far as personalizing pages for users, look into sessions.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.